# Common pattern for returning a mapped object from Http service

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-http

One of my services has a method with this implementation:

```
public getCrawls(page: number): Observable<ICrawl[]>{
        return this._http.get(this._crawlsURL + page)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return {
                    crawls: <ICrawl[]>res.json(),
                    headers: res.headers
                }
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I am doing this as opposed to `.map((res: Response) => <ICrawl[]>res.json())`

So in the consumer component I can also access the headers to make my paginator work:

```
getCrawls(page: number): void {
        this._crawlsService.getCrawls(page)
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.crawls = res.crawls;
                    this.totalItems = res.headers.get('X-Records');
                },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

This works, but both `res.crawls` and `res.headers` are red in WebStorm. (*unresolved variables*) but the code compiles and works.

[image]

Which brings me to be believe this must be the wrong way of doing this. How can I achieve this without having unresolved variables.

Comment: You mean that you have some compilation errors by "unresolved variables"?

Comment: thank you for looking. updated that section.

Comment: If you try this: `res:{crawls:ICrawl[],headers:Headers} => { ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typed your Observable incorrectly. You have `Observable<ICrawl[]>`, you need:

```
interface ICrawlResponse {
    crawls: ICrawl[];
    headers: Headers;
}

public getCrawls(page: number): Observable<ICrawlResponse>{
        return this._http.get(this._crawlsURL + page)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return {
                    crawls: <ICrawl[]>res.json(),
                    headers: res.headers
                }
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: I think this one is quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you simply need to define the type of the object you expect in the callback:

```
getCrawls(page: number): void {
  this._crawlsService.getCrawls(page)
        .subscribe(
          res:{crawls:ICrawl[],headers:Headers} => { // <------
            (...)
          }
        );
```

Comment: For this to work, you'd need to put wrap `(res: {/*type stuff*/})` in parentheses.